# Edit links in GridModel (MVCContrib)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, grid, mvccontrib, html.actionlink

[MvcContrib GridModel : Is it possible to do ActionSyntax in a GridModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458782/mvccontrib-gridmodel-is-it-possible-to-do-actionsyntax-in-a-gridmodel)
I've read this article and it's quite useful but I can't apply this. I don't know if in the newest MVCContrib, they removed the ".Action()" because somehow I cannot access this.

Is there someway i can put the ActionLink of the edit link into a grid model?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the old method has been removed.

Here's how to do it now:

**VB.NET**

First, you pass the Html object into the gridmodel class through the constructor, then you can use it from within the gridmodel class.

```
Imports MvcContrib.UI.Grid

Public Class PersonGridModel
    Inherits GridModel(Of Person)

    Public Sub New(ByVal html as HtmlHelper)
        Column.For(Function(u) html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Person", New With {.id = u.PersonId}, Nothing)).DoNotEncode()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then, in your view you pass it through the constructor:

```
<%=Html.Grid(Model).WithModel(New MemberRetentionTrackingSystem.InboundCallGridViewModel(Html))%>
```

---

**C#**

GridModel:

```
public class PersonGridModel : GridModel {
    public PersonGridModel(HtmlHelper html) {
        Column.For(u => html.ActionLink(“Edit”, “Edit”, “Person”)).DoNotEncode();
    }
}
```

View:

```
< %= Html.Grid(ViewData.Model).WithModel(new PersonGridModel(Html)) %>
```

REFERENCE: http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2009/02/22/rewriting-the-mvccontrib-grid-part-2-new-syntax/ (see [comment from Amitabh](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2009/02/22/rewriting-the-mvccontrib-grid-part-2-new-syntax/#comment-162490571))

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, more recent change, .DoNotEncode() is deprecated now, so use .Encode(false)

Answer (score 0):

First, big thank you to [@Andrew for his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2557225/114029): [Amitabh's question](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2009/02/22/rewriting-the-mvccontrib-grid-part-2-new-syntax/#comment-162490571) and [Skinner's answer](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2009/02/22/rewriting-the-mvccontrib-grid-part-2-new-syntax/#comment-162490574) really solved my doubt. Anyway with ASP.NET MVC 4 I had a hard time trying to figure out why this in a Grid Model wasn't working:

```
Column.For(hospital => html.ActionLink("View Details", "Show", "Foo")).Encode(false);
```

Why? Because I wasn't adding the necessary using directive:

```
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
```

I had only this using suggested by Visual Studio Intellisense:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

Hope it helps anyone facing the same problem!